# How to disable and enable a submit button based on input values

Tags: jquery

I need to enable the next button when values are inserted in the textarea and textarea is not empty. This is my code:

```
 <div class="preview_field content-post-1stpage-next">
      <label class="col-md-5 mt-5" for="content">tags</label><br>
      <p class="text-muted"><small class="text-muted"><textarea disabled="yes" id="preview_tags placeholder="tags...!"></textarea></small></p>
</div>


<div class="post-1stpage-next text-center">
     <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% trans "prev step" %}</button>
     <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'next' %}" disabled="disabled"/>
</div>
```

and this is the jquery code which I used, it even does not enters the its if statement:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#preview_field > label > small > textarea').on('keyup', function() {
    let empty = false;

    $('#preview_tags > textarea').each(function() {
      empty = $(this).val().length == 0;

    });
    if (empty)
      $('.post-1stpage-next input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
       
    else
      $('.post-1stpage-next input').attr('disabled', false);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because your selector which binds the event handler is wrong. `#preview_field` should be `.preview_field`, as it's a class not an id. In addition the `small > textarea` is a child of a `p`, not a `label`.

Once that's fixed you can simplify the logic by providing the boolean outcome of checking the length of the field's value to `prop('disabled'`). Note that the use of `trim()` prevents whitespace being an acceptable value.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.preview_field > p > small > textarea').on('keyup', function() {
    $('.post-1stpage-next input').prop('disabled', this.value.trim().length === 0);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preview_field content-post-1stpage-next">
  <label class="col-md-5 mt-5" for="content">tags</label><br>
  <p class="text-muted">
    <small class="text-muted">
      <textarea id="preview_tags" placeholder="tags...!"></textarea>
    </small>
  </p>
</div>


<div class="post-1stpage-next text-center">
  <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">prev step</button>
  <input type="submit" value="next" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, I can disable or enable the button based on the size of array:

```
//enter code here`enable or disable next button based on the array length
if (array && array.length > 0) {
   $('.post-1stpage-next input').removeAttr('disabled');
}else{
   $('.post-1stpage-next input').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

}